# What happens to the noun ламп with used with an adjective?

Tags: перевод, грамматика

I have compiled an example. With it be correct to assume that a noun with 0-ending would end up with the following syntax?

N: старый ламп

A: старый ламп

G: старого ламп

D: старому ламп

I: старым ламп

P: старом ламп

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **Лампа** is a feminine noun with a very much non-zero ending.
- It's more conventional, in Russian, to list accusative between dative and instrumental.
- An actual zero-ending noun (like **журнал**, which you used in your previous question) would be declined on its own quite independently of the adjective: *старый журнал, старого журнала, старому журналу*, etc. The adjective, on the other hand, inherits the noun's animacy category, and adjusts its accusative form accordingly.

Comment: You are correct that the order is different to what listed, In my region they tend to do it in a different order where I got a little confused. Sorry about that. Thanks for the clarification. Большóе спасибо.